# Table Layout Issue

Tags: html, css

I have the following simplified layout:

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/rersW/

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td style="border:1px solid black;height:300px;width:100px">A</td>
    <td style="border:1px solid black;height:100%">
      <div style="border:1px solid blue;height:100%;width:100px">B</div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

I need the blue outlined div to fill its cell.  I've tried box-sizing on the div and the cell as well as changing the display of both (inline-block, etc.).  Nothing I try is working.

The contents of cell "A" determine the height of the table.

The contents of cell "B" determine the width of its cell.

It must work identically in Chrome, Firefox, Safari, Opera & IE 8+

TIA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Height:100% requires that the parent has an explicit height.  Set the same height in cell b as you do in cell a, which is determining the table height, in this case 300px and the child div will expland.

EDIT
If you can't explicitly define any of the parent heights you will need to use JS/Jquery.  See here http://jsfiddle.net/rersW/3/

Comment: Sure, but I can't do that.  The fixed height in cell "A" is just to simplify the example.  In production, the contents of cell "A" push the height.

Comment: My current solution is to set the height of the div in JS, but it's not a perfect solution.  There's a bit of flicker in some of the browsers before the set height takes effect.

Comment: ya, unfortunately you need to be able to grab the DOM height of cell b and only JS can do that.

Comment: I wound up going back to the JS solution... played around with things a bit and got rid of the flicker.

Answer (score 0):

Try this and post comments if it is not quite right :|

http://jsfiddle.net/rersW/1/

Comment: Thanks, but that doesn't work.  The contents need to go inside the div.  I had tried your suggestion before posting the question, but a position:relative doesn't work properly on a td.

Answer (score 0):

The reason is `height: 100%;` needs to be have a parent with height ***defined*** , or else you have to

- either fix the height.
- or Chain `height: 100%` all the up to body, if no height is fixed anywhere

TO illustrate my point upgrade your markup to this

```
<td valign="top" style="border:1px solid black; height: 300px;">
  <div style="border:1px solid blue;height:100%; display: block;width:100px">B</div>
</td>
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Starx/rersW/2/)

Comment: This is what I'm currently doing.  I'm trying to get away from this solution because the contents of cell "A" change dynamically and whenever they do, I have to go and update the height of the div.  It's a pain and there's a bit of flicker in some of the browsers (esp. Opera) before the new height takes effect.

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE:

I've come up with something that works w/o JS:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <div style="position:relative">
        <table>
          <tr>
            <td style="border:1px solid black;height:300px;width:100px">A</td>
            <td style="border:1px solid black;height:100%">
              <div style="border:1px solid blue;box-sizing:border-box;height:100%;width:100px">&nbsp;</div>
            </td>
          </tr>
        </table>
        <div style="border:1px solid red;height:100%;position:absolute;right:0;top:0;width:100px">B</div>
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Doesn't look pretty when rendered but the production structure doesn't have borders or padding.

Any simpler solutions would be preferred.

Comment: Actually, this doesn't work either... I had forgotten that the table height is sometimes pushed by the "B" div ("B" is taller than "A")... could fix with JS but then I'm back where I started.